# SQL Query - Pull back Date Only

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I thought this would be a simple command to achieve, obviously I missing something in the process. I have SQL Server 2012. I have a table called `Messages` which has a column `MessageTime`. This column stores a date & time in the following format

```
DD-MM-YYYY - 00:00:00
```

I want to extract the first 10 characters and have this is in separate column, so that I can group them further down the query.. But the following command continues to fail, what syntax am I missing here.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), MessageIdTime, 101)
```

Where `MessageIdTime` is the column name....

Thanks
SW

Comment: What is the datatype of MessageIDTime? Is it a string formatted as DD-MM-YYYY - 00:00:00 , or is it a timestamp with seconds precision?

Comment: Are you needing this for display purposes? It's really a formatting question. How do you format a date datatype so that the time component is not presented?

Comment: It's a timestamp

Comment: Basically I'm counting everything in this column, but I want to group the results by the day, so that I end up with a count for each day..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(MessageIdTime, 1, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend extracting it as a date:

```
select try_convert(date, left(MessageIdTime, 10)) as MessageIdDate
```

In fact, you should change your column to contain a date/time type instead of a string.

The date might be so useful that you can add it to the table:

```
alter table t as MessageIdDate as ( try_convert(date, left(MessageIdTime, 10)) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left()` function :

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(MessageIdTime, 10) AS DATE)
```